# Uniform distribution of points on a sphere: only Platonic solids?

Tags: spheres, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

I'm quite sure the only way to uniformly distribute $n$ points on the sphere $S^2$ is by inscribing one of the 5 Platonic solids, thus there only exists a solution for $n=4,6,8,12,20$.

But am I right? And how can this be proven?

***Addendum***

My intuitiv definition of a uniform distribution is: Any 2 adjacent points have the same (spherical) distance; the points adjacent to $p$ are those that have minimal distance from $p$.

This should describe the uniformity of the vertices of a Platonic solid distributed on its circumscribed sphere.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniform"? Does placing them equally spaced around the equator count? This question is impossible to answer without a precise notion of what point arrangements qualify for you.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect I've added my definition of uniformity

Comment: How about [Archimedean solids](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid)?

Comment: Ok, Archimedean solids seem to be fulfilling my condition, too; so I would add, that all adjacent nodes should be equally distributed around a point $p$, i.e. form a regular star (or polygon) around $p$

Comment: I'm really thinking of the most canonical kind of symmetry, as is a uniform distribution on $S^1$. The "view" from any point on the sphere should be the same

Comment: If you put 8 points on a sphere, and space them as far apart as possible (i.e. maximise the smallest distance between any two points) then you don't get a cube but a square anti-prism. This surprised me when I first encountered it, cause with 4, 6, 12, 20 points you do get the other platonic solids.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis This isn’t true with 20 points either; see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212550/distributing-points-evenly-on-a-sphere

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect: Thanks. Though I have read Neil Sloane's paper, I didn't know/remember that.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Thanks. I was thinking of this max-min definition first, it's a quite common criterion. But the example of cube and dodecahedron and those other pictures show that that's not the kind of symmetry I'm looking for

Comment: The way you have defined uniform it in your question now, you can still put for example n equally spaced points around the equator. Each point has only two adjacent points, all at the same distance. In fact, they don't have to be arranged along a great circle, but you could trace any differentiable closed loop on the sphere and pick a large enough number of points so that they can be evenly spaced along the loop. Worse, you could also place the points in pairs, so that the points in a pair are close together some fixed distance, but any two pairs are far apart. Every point has one neighbour.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least two more uniform distributions that fit your current description, one with 14 points, and one with 32 points.

You obtain them by combining the vertices of a pair of dual regular polytopes:

- six vertices of the octahedron + eight vertices of the cube.
  The adjacent points form a regular triangle or square.
- twelve vertices of the icosahedron + 20 vertices of the dodecahedron.
  The adjacent points form a regular triangle or regular pentagon.

[image]